# Parse Query with zero results returns...?

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform

The thing I couldn't quite understand from `Parse.com` documentation is - what does a `PFQuery` (or `Parse.Query` in `CloudCode`) with zero results return?

1. An empty array?
2. nil?
3. An error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A query with no results return an empty array.